# Visual Studio 2010 RC: Build Solution no longer does anything

Tags: build, projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-2010

I don't know if this is a bug or if I've done something weird to my solution, but when I go to build one of my solutions, nothing happens. I've tried the keyboard shortcut, the right-click menu option (as well as the re-build solution option), and the Build >> Build Solution menu option. There's no response, regardless of if my code should compile or not. The status bar simply says "ready".

Also, if I run my solution, it does not get built first. I know this because I've inserted a random "asdf" to prevent the code from compiling properly, and it still runs.

Building a specific project works properly, and I am not experiencing this with any of my other solutions, just this one.

This sounds like a bug, but I wanted to make sure before I submitted it to Microsoft. Has anyone experienced anything like this, and is there a fix for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost certainly something wrong with your individual setup.  Build not functioning in the RC would be a **huge** bug and would have been reported many times by now.

What's most likely happening is that your build configuration is incorrect.  Try the following

- Right Click on your solution and select "Configuration Manager"
- See if build is checked for your projects

The build will only run for projects that are checked.

Comment: It wasn't checked for any of them. I checked them all, and now everything works properly. Thanks!